# Search Input parameter in dataframe and calculate mathematical Values in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am trying to create method which will accept input parameter as either storeid or publicationid and provide min,max,avg on CUSTOMER_RATE column as output

Data:

```
CUSTOMER_RATE|STOREID|PUBLICATIONID
1.0 MSB0045024  AU121879
1.0 MSB0045024  AU121879
1.2 MBR0000616  AU121879
1.0 MBR0000616  AU121879
1.0 MBR0010285  AU121879
1.0 MSB0045024  AU133703
1.0 MSB0023370  AU133703
1.3 MSB0023370  AU133703
1.0 MSB0045024  AU157764
1.0 MSB0023370  AU157764
1.0 MBR0000616  AU157764
1.0 TAR0000018  AU157764
```

I am using Using Spark and scala
Please share your suggestion if it seems logical.

Many Thanks

Comment: Added a sample answer, but it may require changes. Can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are looking for `groupBy..agg..` as below -

```scala
 def getMinMax(df1: Dataframe,   groupByCol: String) =
df1.groupBy(groupByCol).agg(min("CUSTOMER_RATE").as("CUSTOMER_RATE"), max("CUSTOMER_RATE").as("CUSTOMER_RATE"))
  
val groupByCol = "PUBLICATIONID"
val minMaxDf=getMinMax(df1, groupByCol)
```

> change the `groupBycol` as per your requirement

Comment: Many Thanks........ is it possible to do with udf, when we pass PUBLICATIONID calculation based on group by PUBLICATIONID and when input parameter passed as STOREID than caluculation based on group by STOREID..

Comment: I think you are confused with udf and udaf. UDF works on a single row at a time. Not sure what you mean by above comment. anyways you can create method which will take   group by column as input and provide a dataframe having min and max .

Comment: : Sorry new to spark. U are right. how can i create method which will take group by column as input and provide a dataframe having min and max .... appreciate if you can suggest.

Comment: This has nothing to do with spark. Just create simple scala method to get min and max df. Check update. Please feel free to accept upvote if it helps